# How to use ContentTools with Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I'd like to use ContentTools http://getcontenttools.com/ within an application developped with Angular2 too.

Specifically I'm interested what is the best practice to:
- initialize the editor
- inject saved text to component template
- save text modified in component template

Is there any example out there?

Thanks in advance,
Zsolt

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not experienced with Angular, however this issue/thread if you haven't already seen it may be helpful https://github.com/GetmeUK/ContentTools/issues/20

Comment: Did you have any success finding a solution?